# How to send string over Angular $http to C# ASP.NET backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, http, webforms

I want to send a string via Angular $http to my ASP.NET C# backend. I am using web-forms. However, i get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:49730/Default.aspx/get_requested_table 404 (Not Found)
```

My Angular controller looks like this:

```
App.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.request_table = function (tableName) {
       $http
           .post("Default.aspx/get_requested_table", tableName)
           .success(function (data) {
               console.log("Success, it worked!");
           });
   };
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<button ng-click="request_table('tblMain')" type='button'>GET IT</button>
```

And my ASP.NET C# file (aka Default.aspx.cs):

```
public static string myTable;
[WebMethod]
public static string get_requested_table(string tableName)
{
    var myTable = tableName;
    Console.Write(myTable);
    return myTable;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong to be getting this error? How can I use Angular's $http methods to speak with my C# backend?

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager on your page?  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending  a key/value pair

Try

```
$http.post("Default.aspx/get_requested_table", {tableName: tableName})
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I may have been confusing by calling the variable table. It should really be tableName as it is a string. So would I thus have to change the key/value pair to {string:tableName} ?

Comment: key is the object key...make it match back end

Comment: Awesome! That worked! I set {tableName: tableName}, thanks! :)